# How pass a event from deep nested child to parent in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, events, components, parent-child

I have a nested child component that have a output Event, I want listen this event from parent component but I dont know how, I have 4 levels:

I tried to pass the event from child 3 to child 2 and child 2 to child and to Parent, but I think that this is not the best way.

```
-Parent (From this I want listen the event)
--Child
----Child 2
------Child 3 (This have the Event)
```

Comment: In the recent NG Conf, they had a [very instructional video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_q-HL9YX_pk) about that. I highly suggest you to watch it !

Comment: I see answer describing the recommended ways to achieve the same result, but I would be interested in a answer that describes directly how to do what is asked, even if it is not the preferred way.

Comment: The "normal" way is: in child3 put eventEmiter3, in child 2 receive event3 on a Input
and emit that data through the eventEmiter2 to parent, in child1 receive data from eventEmitter2 and emit to parent through another eventEmiter1. nested eventEmiter and Inputs...

Comment: I understand that, but I do not know what is the syntax to implement it in a clean way. I knew in previous angular versions, but for angular2+, I have yet to find an example for it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Source **Dan Wahlin** (ng-conf: Mastering the Subject: Communication Options in RxJS ), it's not recommanded to use OutPut when you have a component in a deeper level that has to communicate with a higher lever component , imagine you have 5 or 6 leves!!, you have to use **Subject** instead:
you can create and Event bus through an observable service

Events here is an enum of events if you want

```
export enum Events{
 'payment done',
  // other events here
 }

@Injectable()
export class EventService {

 private subject$ = new Subject()

 emit(event: EmitEvent) {
    this.subject$.next(event); 
  } 

 on(event: Events, action: any): Subscription {
 return this.subject$.pipe(
  filter((e: EmitEvent) => e.name == event),
  map((e: EmitEvent) => e.value)).subscribe(action);
 }

}
```

so now imagine that you want to emit an event from **Child3** , let's say for example  after a payment is done => notify parent component

```
export class Child3Component implements OnInit {

  constructor(public eventservice : EventService ) {}
  pay(paymentAmount: any) {
    this.eventservice.emit(
      new EmitEvent('payment done',paymentAmount));
  }
}
```

now in your parent component you can call on method like this and you will get the event

```
 export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
   constructor(public eventservice : EventService ) {}
   ngOnInit() {
    this.eventservice.on('payment done', (paymentAmount => console.log(paymentAmount));
   }
 }
```

Comment: What happens if I have 2 events in the child3 that I want to listen them in the parent? How I have to define the ParentComponent Class (
I mean the part of this.eventservice.on having 2 events to listen to)?

Comment: you have to add another call :                                       this.eventservice.on('payment done', (paymentAmount => console.log(paymentAmount));   this.eventservice.on('customer added', (customer=> console.log(customer));

Comment: Its not define EmitEvent, I understand that is a created class, should this class have name (EventName) and value?

Comment: What happens if (like I have a situation now) you're displaying the parent component 3 times in the view (with it's children)? Sharing an Observable in the service won't work this time.

Comment: @TJ96 - this should work if you want all instances to react the same. If they should react differently, then you need to add some identifiers to your event info class (`EmitEvent` class in this example), and then some processing logic in your component to only handle events meant for it. You can just do nothing with the event if you find out the current component should not handle it.

Comment: Maybe late here however I have a question here . I believe this pattern will not work if you have a requirement where the event needs to be emitted from any of the lifecycle events as that will give the infamous expressionchangedafteritwaschecked error. However if we use standard EvenEmitter class( which also extends subject), then this can be achieved in both cases. Because in my case where I have to emit event from lifecycle method I can do it by isAsync flag as true and otherwise emit it synchronously. And use subscribe method of EventEmitter itself to listen to events. Makes sense?

Comment: Kindly note EventEmitter can be used in normal service as well instead just like it can be used through @Output.

Comment: What is EmitEvent here, for code completeness, should it not be shown here as well ?

Answer (score 8):

Though you can use an `@Output` event emitter to do this, I'd suggest that you create a shared service instead that will handle the communications since there are quite many levels of nesting.

You can do something like below, and inject the service in both of your components. One will emit the message (your nested child component), and one will listen for the messages (your top level component).

Define your service

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CommunicationService {
    @Output() message$: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter();

    sendMessage(message: String) {
        this.change.emit(message)
    }
}
```

Inject it in your components

```
constructor(private communicationService: CommunicationService) { }
```

In the component where you will send the message from

```
sendMessage() {
    this.communicationService.sendMessage('This is a message from deep below!');
}
```

And in your listener component, subscribe to the event emitter

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.communicationService.message$.subscribe(message => {
      console.log(message);
    });
}
```

Comment: I added the short code on how to inject the `CommunicationService` in your components! You'll have to adapt it to fit your need since I don't know what you're trying to send between the components!