# Input Output vs ngrx Dispatch Oftype

Tags: angular, ngrx

Tell me please what is the best way to communicate data between components in angular if you use Ngrx Store.

1. Use Input Output
2. Use dispatch(action) ofType(action)

For example Component1 -> send data to -> Component2. After some time business tell me add new service, so I decide to create a new Component3 and add it between them.

So now I have to modify data flow. Component1 -> Component3 -> Component2.
So in which way it would be more code clean and simple to understand, with `input outpt` or `despatch(action) ofType(action)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think it depends on the size of your app and how many levels you have between components, imagine that you have a child5 component that have to communicate with child1, in that case it's not a good idea to use Input Output, on the picture bellow, if **child** component have to communicate to **Grandparent** it has to pass by **Parent**, the Parent participate in the flow even if it doesn't have anything to do with that data

[image]

better way here is to use **Subject** and create and **EventBus**, check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/56291422/4399281

**Ngrx store** is the best options but if you really need it, don't implement a state management if you have few components only

Comment: i have a middle application, more then 40 components

Comment: if you have a lot of communications between components, you can use state management, depends on how much time you have, subject solution is faster and easier

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, if you're already using NgRx, you should stick to its patterns and pass all application state through the Store.

Inputs and Outputs can quickly become annoying to track, especially as an app becomes more complex. What if you want to add a feature which uses the same data? If you're already using the Store, you simply need to subscribe to the bit you need.

There are undoubtedly situations in which you'll want to use custom properties and events, but if you've chosen to use NgRx, you'll almost always want to use the Store for state management. Otherwise, why install it?

Comment: But in many cases u cant avoid to use inputs and outputs, for example, a parent "a" that have two instances of child "b" but with different data, selector inside the component "b" increase the acomplishment and reduce its reausability, at least i think so. another example its component inside ngFor, the only clear way that i think to solve these cases its an input and output solution. Sorry for my english. I would appreciate your point of view about this because i want to clarify tthis topic for me

Comment: Your English is better than you think it is :) rereading this answer makes me want to add some nuance to it. There is absolutely a place for Input/Output communication between components, even in an app where you use a state management system. It's really a case-specific decision, but you can, for example, use the smart/dumb pattern, with a parent component getting all the data from the store and passing it to its children via attribute binding. Outputs are also really handy when reusing components in different areas of an app.